# How can I solve ? Too many re-renders , React limits the number of renders

Tags: html, reactjs

I try to add and remove class on three buttons.
When I click, a class should be add and remove on others buttons.

I have a const:

```
const [genderActive, setGenderActive] = useState('');
const isGenderActive = (active) => {
   setGenderActive(active);
};
```

the HTML:

```
<div aria-label="title" role="group" class="btn-group">
   <button name="0" type="button" className={genderActive === 0 ? 'selected btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-primary' } onClick={isGenderActive(0)}>M.</button>
   <button name="1" type="button" className={genderActive === 1 ? 'selected btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-primary' } onClick={isGenderActive(1)}>Mme.</button>
   <button name="2" type="button" className={genderActive === 2 ? 'selected btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-primary' } onClick={isGenderActive(2)}>Mx</button>
</div>
```

When I compile the react I have an error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I have find multiple post with this error but I can't solve the problem.

Do you how I can solve this one ?

Comment: change `onClick={isGenderActive(0)}` to `onClick={() => isGenderActive(0)}` and do it for all instances

Comment: @Apostolos that's work, thanks you

Comment: Please note that right now every time the HTML content is parsed, the function is called. What @Apostolos said, will prevent that by wrapping it in another function which is only attaching the event handler and not executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `isGenderActive` on render. So state change and re-render. You just update to make sure `isGenderActive` only call when click:

```
onClick={() => isGenderActive(0)}
```